# JTAPI - How to intercept a call from CUCM

Tags: jtapi, cisco-jtapi

I want to write an easy as short as possible java program using JTAPI, that connects to the CUCM and gets a notification when a call is done by the user.
In other words, i want to make a journal live journal for the user showing who making the calling (always the user) who is being called, and the duration.

Answer (score 0):

JTrace application (with source code) is part of Cisco JTAPI installation. Using this application you can observe all the call activity of the user. You need to enable/configure the user for CTI Application on CUCM admin and use those credentials to start JTrace.